# Cranky about bookmarks: Cant use Google toolbar in Firefox, cant get to my google bookmarks in Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, firefox-extensions, google-workspace

I have been using the google bookmarks feature in the google toobar to keep my bookmarks in sync between my many different computers. I liked it because it allowed me to keep one set of bookmarks across Windows, Linux and Mac machines.
Now with the newest update of Firefox (7.0.1)this feature has stopped working at all.
My options are to change to Firefox sync, or use something else like Xmarks.
I tried Chrome, but strangely it does not integrate with Google bookmarks!??

I have invested heavily in creating a large collection of bookmarks in the Google Bookmarks app. I don't really want to have to go through the pain of migrating all of those bookmarks again to another place.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using XMarks since it came out.

http://www.xmarks.com/about/features/overview